# Nueva Política de Cookies 2018

Tags: html, cookies

me gustaría saber si a día de hoy es obligatorio mostrar en nuestra web el mensaje de aviso de Cookies como había que hacer anteriormente, porque si mal no he leído, la nueva ley no obliga a tener que mostrar este mensaje cada vez que un usuario accede a nuestra web. Por favor, si hay algún compañero de España y que sepa acerca de este tema, es decir, de como está regulación en España, que me ayude. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Para cualquier asunto legal, siempre será sano acudir a una asesoría legal.

Comment: creo que has leído mal en este caso. Asesórate legalmente